# Login Mechanism in Windows 10 UWP App Development?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I see lot of difference between Win 8.1 and Win 10 Apps. Login used to be in settings in Win 8.1. How to implement custom login in Win 10? Which is the right component or control for it? Also how to implement carousel panel in XAML which is similar to Win 10 Store App?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

> How to implement custom login in Win 10? Which is the right component or control for it?

See:

- [Guidelines for login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965453.aspx)
- [Authentication and user identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt270184.aspx)

> How to implement carousel panel in XAML which is similar to Win 10
>   Store App?

There is no carousel control like in Store App right out of the box. However, Pivot control has similar functionality, see [Guidelines for tabs and pivots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997788.aspx) -> The Pivot control -> Carousel section. If you edited the template in Blend For Visual studio it could look just like the carousel in store app although it won't be easy.

Another option is to google for 3rd party control or create your own.

---

If you are serious about creating apps for windows, you should really read all the guidelines for Universal Windows App [design](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/design) and [development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt244352.aspx).

If you look at what's measued in microsoft exams:

- [70-354 - UWP – App Architecture and UX/UI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/learning/exam-70-354.aspx)
- [70-355 - UWP – App Data, Services and Coding Patterns](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/learning/exam-70-355.aspx)

you will have very good overview of what is recommended to know. For each exam there use to be a great book called Exam Prepartion Guide, but since these exams are new and currently still in beta, the books has not been published yet.